# Return MySQL SELECT as JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have this php code to build the result of my MYSQL into JSON:

```
<?php
$mysql_db_hostname = "localhost";
$mysql_db_user = "root";
$mysql_db_password = "";
$mysql_db_database = "essensplan";


$con = @mysqli_connect($mysql_db_hostname, $mysql_db_user, $mysql_db_password, $mysql_db_database);

if (!$con) {
 trigger_error('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$var = array();
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM beispiel";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

while($obj = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) { $var[] = $obj; }

echo '{"users":'.json_encode($var).'}';
?>
```

The PHP script work on my Apache and the PHP Version is 5.5.11.
But when I call the script, there only shows `{users:}` and the json data from the mysql data base is missed. Have anybody an idea?

EDIT: I found a solution. After connect to the database set this:

```
mysqli_set_charset($con, 'utf8');
```

Comment: You should elaborate on the step between where it was working and afterwards not. Enable error_reporting, mysqli_error, check charset, var_dump the result set, use an IDE debugger etc.

Comment: special characters can break json and it will return null. You might want to utf8_encode them. However, without seeing the table structure and data, it's difficult to say. Can you var_dump the contents of $var ?

Comment: In my table there are 4 rows with double and 4 rows with text in utf8_encode_german2.

Answer (score 1):

You should modify the part after you've checked for the connection error as so:

```
$var = array();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM beispiel";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

while($obj = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) { 
    $var['users'][] = $obj; 
}

echo json_encode($var);
```

If for example your returned results are arrays as so

```
array(
    'name' => 'person1',
    'age' =>  25
),
array(
    'name' => 'person2',
    'age' => 30
),
array(
    'name' => 'person3',
    'age' => 22
)
```

Then your returned JSON response will be as so:

```
{"user":[{"name":"person1","age":25},{"name":"person2","age":30},{"name":"person3","age":22}]}
```

Hope that solved your problem, if any modifications are required, please provide more info.

Comment: Thanks, but it also don't work. :( My db calls 'essensplan' and the table names 'beispiele' and in example one column named 'Hauptspeise'. But it shows nothing, the response in json is empty.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What response is your application expecting? Is the response empty for you?

Comment: **Edit: You could try removing the 'at' character (@) from this line `$con = @mysqli_connect(....`. Adding that character means if there are any errors invoked by that call, it will be muted - so you have no idea if there actually is an error there. After removing it, try adding `error_reporting(E_ALL);` before the above mentioned row (only add it while trying to solve this problem). If there are any errors, it will show them all for you - this way we might get a bit closer to finding your problem as I don't see anything else in your code that should cause this issue.

Comment: I put the `error_reporting(E_ALL);` function in it but there is also all empty, no error code and no json script. The database works, with only showing the normal data base with echo there are the data from my table. Is there any special setting for json with php? Or is there a `error_reporting` for `json_encode`?

Comment: Try adding the following row below `$var['users'][] = $obj;`: `print_r($obj);` this will print a comprehensible representation of the given object, or to put it simple, show how PHP sees the variable.

Comment: I found the problem, in mysql there are all rows utf-8 encoded. With `mysqli_set_charset($con, 'utf8');` it work now!